# Nicely packed story - a better way to say it?

Tags: phrases, sentence

"She told us a story, it was a very nicely packed story but..." Is there a better way to say "nicely packed story"?

There was this person who gave us a speech and she shared a personal story. It was a nice story, "nicely packed" as a called it but when you look closely, the story pointed to the wrong thing and it was bad, but she made it sound very good. So what I want to do is to create a sentence which says she told us a very nicely packed story, beautiful on the outside, sounds great, but really rotten on the inside when you think about it.

Comment: I like *nicely packed*, actually. Can you try to elaborate on exactly *how* you'd like to improve it? Asked differently: what's wrong with it? Are you a non-native speaker who would like us to simply elaborate on its likely meaning (if so, the more context you can [edit] into your question, the better)? Or perhaps you're concerned it's not formal enough for some use you want to put it to (in that case, describe for us how and where you *would* like to use it)?

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for helping me out. I'm not a native speaker so I'm asking just to check if that phrase would work or is there a better one which I don't know about.

Comment: Sure, no problem, let's find out. Can you [edit] your question to elaborate on what you mean by "nicely packed story"? Spell out for us all the ideas and nuances you wish to convey with those words. Give us examples of *how* the story was nicely packed, and *what it means* to be nicely packed, and maybe even what it means to be *poorly packed*. The more details you give us, the more specific and helpful we can be in our suggestions.

Comment: Here is what happened.... there was this person who gave us a speech and she shared a personal story. It was a nice story, "nicely packed" as a called it but when you look closely, story pointed to the wrong thing and it was bad, but she made it sound very good. So what I want to do is to create a sentence which says she told as a very nicely packed story, beautiful on the outside, sounds great, but really rotten on the inside when you think about it.

Comment: Now *that* information is *definitely* worth [including in your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/315760/edit)!

Comment: Yes, I should have included it. So, "nicely packed story" should work... great. Thanks Dan, I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: I was trying to inspire you to edit your question so that you'd get more and better answers, rather than a short conversation with just me in the comments. But if you're preparing to leave, may I suggest as ***slickly packaged story***?

Comment: I agree that "packaged" may carry connotations closer to what you seem to be trying to convey than does "packed", at least to my American ear.

Comment: I'm very curious what the story was, now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try *well presented*.

> **Present** *verb*
>   4.1 Exhibit (a particular state or appearance) to others
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/present?q=presented#present-2)

Here are a couple of examples from the web:

- "A well-developed and presented story can cut across age barriers ..." - [Barry McWilliams](http://www.eldrbarry.net/roos/eest.htm)
- "A good and well-presented story is successful in ..." - [storytellingday.net](http://www.storytellingday.net/art-of-storytelling-an-overview.html)

Your sentence would then be "She told us a story, it was a very *well presented* story but..."

Answer (score 0):

The ordinary way to put this would be: *well told*.

Comment: That doesn't indicate that the "moral" of the story was bad though.